# List Multiple Databases from multiple servers in same list

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I use Sql Server Management Studio and have 3 servers each with ~100 databases listed in alphabetical order.  Is there a plugin or some way that I can get all the databases into one list in alphabetical order instead of having separate drop down lists of databases for each server?  It is hard to remember which server a database is in which results in me wasting time looking through each server to find the db I need to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only three servers, get the dropdown lists of each    server into one list each.

Take them to Excel or a spreadsheet    application.

If necessary, for a given database, apply a Serial    Number column in Excel, will come in handy for any sorting later.

Add a column that indicates the Server Name to which the database    belongs.

If necessary, add an overall Serial Number in another    column.

Now you could use the Excel spreadsheet to look for a given    database.

Even better, if you want to avoid looking for a    spreadsheet every time,  export this spreadsheet back to one of the    servers as a table, so you can find from that particular database,    about tables in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

1. The SqlTreeo Plugin can help in this case: http://www.sqltreeo.com/wp/. It allows you to create custom folders for databases, stored procedures, tables, views and user defined functions.
2. SQLHandy Groupie is another plugin with a similar function. It can be found here: http://www.skilledsoftware.com/